# SWIFT how to sort 2D array in 2nd dimension without having to transpose

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

is there a way to sort a 2D array such that

```
[[9,8,7]
 [6,1,4]]
```

becomes

```
[[7,8,9]
 [4,1,6]]
```

I am building a table for a graph from a structure

```
var graphPoints = [[Double]]()
graphPoints.append(jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.map { ($0.Date.timeIntervalSince1970) })
graphPoints.append(jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.map { Double($0.Score) })
graphPoints.append(jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.map { Double($0.avDuration) })
graphPoints.append(jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.map { Double($0.Tries) })
// var sortedGraphPoints = graphPoints.sort { ($0[0]) < ($1[0]) }
var sortedGraphPoints = graphPoints.sort { ([0]$0) < ([0]$1) }
```

The line marked as a comment runs, however, sorts for the 1st element of each inner array, meaning it sorts the values within each data set instead sorting all data sets by date.

The last line results in the error "Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two '([Int], [Double])' operands"

I found some code to transpose the array. But I did not really understand the code (I am new to Swift) and I would prefer keeping the structure.

Comment: This is a *really* strange bit of code. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So you want to keep the associations between 7 and 4, 8 and 1, and 9 and 4 intact? If so, it's maybe better to put them in structs or tuples

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica sorry :-) So, I am reading a JSON file into a variable (jsonResult). This variable is based on a structure with an array called highscoreRecord. This array holds a sub structure with elements Date, Score, etc. Now I want to plot Score etc over time. So I store this in graphPoints. Now I would like to sort by date

Comment: @Gereon exactly. Does populating the struct from my arrays work likewise to populating the array? I was quite happy having figured out how to do this :-) The complication included here is the type conversion from date() to double to make downstream calculations a bit easier

Comment: @w461  I understand the code, but what's weird is that you have all this rich type data (names like `Tries`, `Date`, `avDuration`, etc.) that you start out with, you collapse it down into a bunch of arrays (losing all that), then wondering how to sort by the data you just discarded. Gereon pointed you in a good direction. Don't serialize your data too early. Do it at the last possible step before sending it out to an external system (graphing library, web request, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell from your question, but apparently you have your data already organized in a struct that looks something like this:

```
struct HighscoreRecord: Decodable {
    let date: Date
    let score: Int
    let avDuration: Int
    let tries: Int
}
```

and your `jsonResult!.highscoreRecord` is of type `[HighscoreRecord]`.

If you absolutely need to convert those to your `graphPoints` array, you should simply do the sorting *before* the conversion, as it is trivially easy:

```
let sortedRecords = jsonResult!.highscoreRecord.sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
```

and then use that as the input to your `map` calls.

PS: Try to avoid force-unwrapping via `!` if you can.

Comment: Genius! That is a simple workaround! Not sure if there is an easier way than converting to graphPoints. I am spending 99% of my brain understanding Swift and object oriented programming. I was very good in C and did some light OOP with VBA later. But this now is a different story...